# Comments with Custom post_type and Custom post_status is not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use Comments in my Custom post type ( **book** ) with custom post_status ( **ets_open**, **ets_pending**, **ets_closed** ).

I did added comments support in my custom post type like this

```
'supports'           => array( 'comments' )
```

but its not showing the comment box in the edit/add custom post type page. But when i change post_status to **publish**. It shows.

Well, Anyone knows, why its not showing with my custom statuses?

Comment: do you want comment form to be displayed when in draft as well

Comment: No, only on my custom statuses.